# Can a Cloud Spanner child table have the same primary key as the parent table?

Tags: parent-child, primary-key, google-cloud-spanner

Can a Cloud Spanner child table define the same primary key that the parent table uses (with the child is interleaved in the parent)? I know the child's primary key must use the parent's primary key as a prefix, but is the child key *required* to use at least one additional column? If it's permitted to use the same key, is it bad practice? And if it's not permitted, why not?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Furniture (
  FurnitureId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
  MakerId INT64 NOT NULL,
  // additional fields here...
) PRIMARY KEY (FurnitureId, MakerId);

CREATE TABLE FurnitureHistory (
  FurnitureId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
  MakerId INT64 NOT NULL,
  // additional fields here...
) PRIMARY KEY (FurnitureId, MakerId),
  INTERLEAVE IN PARENT Furniture;
```

Thanks!
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is permitted, but it seems a little bit strange at first hand. This data model will allow you to insert at most one child row for each parent row. This is quite similar to adding a couple of optional fields to the parent table, but with these optional fields logically separated from the parent table. So I guess this makes sense if:

- You have a number of additional fields that have a logical different meaning, which gives you a reason for storing them in a child table.

And/or

- The additional fields should either not be filled at all, or all (or at least more than one) should be filled when one of them are filled.